# Appropriate fan speed for a Dell PowerEdge T710

Tags: performance, dell-poweredge, physical-environment

We have a DELL PowerEdge T710 in our office and it is really really noisy, the fans sound like vacuum cleaners! The discussion is whether the server is malconfigured and can be made more silent or if the fans need to run at this speed and the server has to be moved to another room then.

Now I'm trying to figure out if the current speed of the fans is actually appropriate for the environment temperature and the current stress of the server.

The data:

- Dell Poweredge T710
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5675 @ 3.07GHz
- Memory 36851.0 MB
- VMware ESXi, 5.5.0
- The fans running at:
  [image: fanspeed]
- with ambient temperature of 32 Degrees C
- and a performanceload always under 25%
  [image: CPU load]

Is there a rule of thumbs about fan speeds? What do you think about my provided data?
I actually think 4680 RPM is way to fast for a load of only under 25% and a temperature of only 32 Degrees C, but I'm new to this kind of issue and that's why I'm asking you, thanks for any advise on this! :)

Comment: Servers aren't generally optimized to be quiet.

Comment: Ambient temps of 32 deg C aren't exactly within nominal range, either...

Comment: Yes I'm aware of servers always being a bit noisy :) but this one is extremely noisy. I'm having a T320 standing next to me, which is actually under heavy load sometimes and never gets noisy though, that is kind of a noise reference for us ;) the t320 is running at 25 deg C, is that more within normal range? Sounds like the fan RPM is within normal range according to the temperature then?

Comment: Those numbers roughly jibe with an R710 that I looked at. I tend to think the machine is just that loud.